# Clockwise and counterclockwise path around the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-cd, loops

I want to draw the following
[image]

At first I thought of doing something like a dipole but then I realized that it was not like that, it is just a curve that returns it to the origin of coordinates in a clockwise or counterclockwise direction. **My wrong attempt was**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{% 
    attach arrow/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length},bend]}] plot[smooth]
         coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },
     attach arrow/.default=0.5,
     arc arrow/.cd,length/.initial=2mm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,1}
  \draw[red,thick,attach arrow/.list={1/4}] (0,\x) circle [radius=\x+1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a macro `\loops` that draws your figure. `\loops{2}\hspace{2cm}\loops[<]{4}` produces the following:

[image]

The required argument is the number of loops around the origin. The optional argument is `<` for clockwise orientation, empty for counterclockwise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{mycurve/.style={thick, looseness=1.7, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0 with {\arrow{#1}}}, postaction={decorate}},
    mycurve/.default={>}}
    
\newcommand{\loops}[2][>]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \xx using {1+mod(int(\x),#2)}] in {1,...,#2}{
\draw[mycurve=#1](\x,0)to[out=90, in=90](-\x,0);
\draw[mycurve=#1](-\x,0)to[out=-90, in=-90](\xx,0);
}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\loops{2}\hspace{2cm}\loops[<]{4}

\end{document}
```

For a more compact look you can change the `\draw` commands:

```
\draw[mycurve=#1](.5+.5*\x,0)to[out=90, in=90](-.5-.5*\x,0);
\draw[mycurve=#1](-.5-.5*\x,0)to[out=-90, in=-90](.5+.5*\xx,0);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooo much!! Is it possible to use these arrows "-stealth" or maybe another style? (This is just to learn a little more and add if you need it)

Comment: Yes. Just add `>=stealth` to the tikzset. `\tikzset{mycurve/.style={>=stealth, thick, looseness=1.7,...`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!